Can I mount blinds to a vinyl window sill?
Ordered some inside mount cellular blinds and the instructions say just to mount them to the top part of the window sill. Problem is, seems like we have vinyl window sills with nothing behind them, as we drilled into them and the screw just shot straight in without resistance. Is there a way to mount anything up or should we have gone for outside mount? Screw was about 1.5 and we were about 10" away from the corner.


Longer screws might help.  Depending on house construction you will have wood or cement above that window.

Got pics of the holes?

Thanks for all the tips guys. Wood framing around the window confirmed so went with linger screws and it made it nice and sturdy.

The sill is the bottom of the window.  I believe you are misspeaking about the various parts of a window frame.
That said,  the material is not important. Wood, Vinyl, Aluminium all should be sufficient to hold the blind bracket if the proper screws are used.  You may need screws expressly made for vinyl.  Or get  screws that are longer that go through the trim to the wood behind it.

Tried the longer screws and it worked! 4 inch wood screws got it sitting nice and secure
